# Выполнить метод из partial class c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть стандартное главное окно WPF внутри которого есть незатейливый метод:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

    public void LoadDataToDataGrid()
    {
                LoadDataFromSqlToDataGrid sqlToDataGrid = new LoadDataFromSqlToDataGrid();
                PV.ItemsSource = sqlToDataGrid.LoadTableFromSQLToDataTable().DefaultView;

                PV.Columns[0].Header = "ID";
    }
}
```

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что у меня не получается выполнить метод `LoadDataToDataGrid()` из другого класса. Обычные попытки создать экземпляр окна не приводят к желаемому результату.

Если я в любом другом классе типа:

```
  public class ClassName
{
   // SomeCode
}
```

Начну набирать MainWindow, Интеллисенс мне ничего не предложит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы создаете экземпляр класса MainWindow, то метод должен быть и всё должно работать, покажите кода, как вы это делаете!

Comment: @YuryBakharev дополнил

Comment: Application.Current.MainWindow.LoadDataToDataGrid()

Comment: @Любитель ну значит у вас не прописаны namespace , того места где реализован класс  MainWindow, либо вы вообще из другого проекта пытаетесь вызвать.